# Query Azure Table with Shared Access Signature returns not implemented, but with connection string works

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Spend many hours to try to sort this out.

I have a table and want to create a read-only SAS and give to client components to read access. But never succeed.

If just use connection string and hook up table directly like this:

```
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(SliStorageConnection);

    // Create the table client.
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

    var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(GlobalFilterTable);

    TableOperation tableOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<TableEntity>(FilterTablePartition, "filter1");
    TableResult tableResult = table.Execute(tableOperation);
```

It works fine. But with SAS like below, always returns `501 Not Implemented`

```
    var policy = new SharedAccessTablePolicy
    {
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
        Permissions = SharedAccessTablePermissions.Query
    };

    string sas = table.GetSharedAccessSignature(
        policy,
        null,
        FilterTablePartition,
        String.Empty,
        FilterTablePartition,
        String.Empty);

    Uri tableSasUri = new Uri(table.Uri, sas);
    AccessTable(tableSasUri.AbsoluteUri.ToString());

private static void AccessTable(string tableSas)
{
    string filterTableBaseUrl = tableSas.Substring(0, tableSas.IndexOf('?'));

    var filterTableSasCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tableSas.Substring(filterTableBaseUrl.Length));
    CloudTableClient tableClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri(filterTableBaseUrl), filterTableSasCredentials);

    var _manifestFilterCloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(GlobalFilterTable);

    TableOperation tableOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<TableEntity>(FilterTablePartition, "filter1");
    TableResult tableResult = _manifestFilterCloudTable.Execute(tableOperation);
}
```

Tried different ways, give less than 1 hour time, named or anonymous policy identifier, use signature only ("sig") to create `StorageCredentials`. All failed with different errors. Mostly `501 not implemented`, sometime `resource not found`, sometimes `403 Forbidden`.

Couldn't find useful info online. I am using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` version 3.1 SDK.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the following two lines of code:

```
CloudTableClient tableClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri(filterTableBaseUrl), filterTableSasCredentials);

    var _manifestFilterCloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(GlobalFilterTable);
```

Basically what is happening is that the table name is repeated twice in the table URL in `manifestFilterCloudTable`. When you're creating `CloudTableClient`, the URI should not include the table name. It should only be something like `https://[youraccountname].table.core.windows.net`.

Please use the following code in your `AccessTable` method:

```
        string filterTableBaseUrl = tableSas.Substring(0, tableSas.IndexOf('?'));
        var filterTableSasCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tableSas.Substring(filterTableBaseUrl.Length));
        filterTableBaseUrl = filterTableBaseUrl.Substring(0, filterTableBaseUrl.LastIndexOf("/"));
        tableClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri(filterTableBaseUrl), filterTableSasCredentials);

        var _manifestFilterCloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("Address");

        TableOperation tableOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<TableEntity>(FilterTablePartition, "filter1");
        TableResult tableResult = _manifestFilterCloudTable.Execute(tableOperation);
```

Another thing I noticed that for SharedAccessPolicy, you're using `DateTime.Now`. Depending on the timezone where the code is executed, you may run into 403 errors because date/time in Azure is in UTC. Please use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead.

Comment: You nailed it. I couldn't find it until you point it out. Removing table name from uri make it work. Thank you very much.